# How to add app icons to the dropdown menu?

Tags: xubuntu, menu

I'm trying to figure out how to add a category **Development** and sub-icons within that category.

[image]

At work, I was able to set up PyCharm and a **Development** category appeared, and when I hovered over it, it would show PyCharm, Postgres, Sublime Text, etc

Unfortunately, I don't remember how I did it. Right now I'm trying to set it up like that for my laptop.

Answer (score 2):

Try Alacarte.

> Alacarte is an easy-to-use menu editor for GNOME that can add and edit
>   new entries and menus. It works with the freedesktop.org menu
>   specification and should work with any desktop environment that uses
>   the spec.

To install [**Alacarte** [image: Install comixcursors-lefthanded]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/precise/alacarte/)

<sup>Source:Ubuntu Apps</sup>